# pass a character vector as the funs argument for summarize_at

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a function that takes an argument `funs` that is a string of functions to be applied to a set of variables `vars`. The simplest way to do this seemed to be to use dplyr's `summarize_at` and the SE version of `funs` function.

This works with the functions that are built-in R but doesn't seem to work with user-defined functions. It reports an error that it can't find the user-defined function. However, `summarize_at` works when done "manually."

This function is part of a larger function that produces a box for a Shiny Dashboard. I'd prefer not to have (and have to maintain) a different Shiny module for each type of box (each function and function argument combination).

A minimal reproducible example is below:

```
# function to compute summary stat
compute_box_value <- function(data, vars, funs) {
  f = funs_(funs)
  result <- data %>% 
    summarize_at(.cols = vars, .funs = f)
}

# simple user defined function that gets count of rows with certain values of x
equals <- function(x, test_value) {
  sum(x %in% test_value)
}

x <- data.frame(value = sample(1:5, 10, TRUE))

vars <- c("value")

# this works
print(compute_box_value(x, vars, "mean(., na.rm = TRUE)"))

# this works
summarize_at(x, vars, .funs = "equals", test_value = 1)

# this doesn't work (error: couldn't find function equals)
print(compute_box_value(x, vars, "equals(., test_value = 1)"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the formula (`~`) instead of string:

```
print(compute_box_value(x, vars, ~equals(., test_value = 1)))
```

Which gives:

```
#  value
#1     3
```

From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html):

> It’s best to use a formula because a *formula captures both the
>   expression to evaluate and the environment where the evaluation
>   occurs*. This is important if the expression is a mixture of variables
>   in a data frame and objects in the local environment:

Comment: That got halfway. The formula works but not with a character string. I found that nesting the character string inside `eval(parse())` got the rest of the way there. Marking as answer.

Comment: I should add that the string is required because of how it's nested inside a larger function in my actual code. I don't directly call `compute_box_value()` and so can't directly enter the argument as a non-string argument.

Comment: @iacobus Glad it helped ! Feel free to add any additionnal information that wasn't covered and could benefit future readers. You could also add these precisions to your question.

Comment: There isn't much to add - when the function is passed as a character it needs to be `print(compute_box_value(x, vars, eval(parse(text = "~equals(., test_value = 1)")))`. The `eval(parse())` is required to make R evaluate the string as an argument.